# I would like to extract the words from ":" to slash

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I have asked this question before and now i edit it because i found some lines that doesn't correspond to the format i gave before ...

---

here's an example of the lines:

```
data = "09:55:04.125 mta         Messages       I Doc O:SERVER (NVS:SMTP/me@domain.com) R:NVS:FAXG3.I0.0101 mid:6393"
data2= "09:55:05.045 mta         Messages       I Doc O:SERVER (NVS:SMTP/me@domain.com) R:ADMIN (NVS:SMTP.0/me@domain.fr) mid:6397"
```

---

at first i have matched what's between the slash and two points but i've noticed that there's some lines like the first where the type "FAXG3.I0.0101" isn't followed by a slash

---

here's the regex i use:

```
exp = result = re.findall(r'[\w\.]+(?=:*)',data) # type S & D
```

---

the result i want is 'SMTP','FAXG3.I0.0101' for the first line and 'SMTP','SMTP.0' for the second. 
can someone help correcting my regex to get that ??

Comment: It seems your regex doesn't quite fit the title of your question. You're checking if there is 0 or more `:` **after** your match, not before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the regex such that it also accepts '.' as a valid character, e.g.:

```
import re 
data = "This is a test message I Res O:Myself (KTP:SMTP/me@domain.com) R:KTP:SMS.CLASS/+345854595 id:21"
result = re.findall(r'[\w\.]+(?=:*/)',data)
print result

['SMTP', 'SMS.CLASS']
```

The `[\w\.]+` says you'll accept a sequence consisting of at least one 'any alphanumeric character and the underscore' (`\w`) or `.` (`\.` - it needs to be escaped, as `.` otherwise means 'any character').

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
result = re.findall(r'(?<=:)[\w.]+(?=/)',data)
```

Saying "a sequence of alphanumerical characters (or underscore or dot) between `:` and a `/`".